# Not able to register a third party DLL even with elevated rights

Tags: regsvr32

I have been trying to register a 
third party dll file using the regsvr32 command, but it keeps giving me the error
"The module "test.dll" was loaded but the call to DLLRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005."

I am running it with elevated commands in CMD but still same issues.

Has some one faced similar issues and knows a possible solution for it.

Thanks